# Direction of principle axes for a closed curve

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, quadratic-forms, symmetry

Suppose we have been given some closed curve, described by $f(x,y)$. Is there any way to figure out, what are the directions of the principle axes?

I know how to do it if $f(x,y)$ is a degree-$2$ polynomial. The two methods I've seen, do the some in the following way :

(i) Consider $f(x,y)$ to be a quadratic form, and then write it in matrix form. Then find the eigenvectors, that diagonalize the matrix. These eigenvectors are the directions of the principal axes. I believe this is the same as writing the hessian matrix for the curve and then finding the eigenvectors.

(ii)Consider a line $y=mx$. Substitute this into the equation and find an expression for $x^2$. If the curve is centered about the origin, the square of the distance of any point on the curve, to the origin would be $x^2+y^2 = x^2(1+m^2)$ Plug the expression for $x^2$ into this, and we'll get a function $g(m)$. Then we find the maxima of $g(m)$ w.r.t m, by setting $\frac{ d g(m)}{dm} = 0$.

We'd obtain values of 'm'. Plugging this back into $y=mx$, we get our principle axes vectors. I don't understand the exact intuition behind this, if someone can explain, that would be helpful. I've seen someone do this in a question, I'm attaching a link to it : [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262224).

In this link, you see the two above methods applied to solve a problem. However, what if the curve was of a higher degree. How do we solve the problem?

For example, say $f(x) = x^4+9y^2-10xy=100$. How do I find the directions of the principal axes for this curve? Using the second method as described above, I obtain 4 values of $m$. These are $m=2.14612,-2.63542,\infty, \frac{5-\sqrt{205}}{9} $ Hence I'm obtaining 4 different axes. Which ones if any of these, are the principal axes?

Or is there any other way to solve these kinds of problems. Writing a curve in matrix form and finding eigenvectors, seems to be the easiest, and most intuitive, but how do I write a polynomial of degree higher than $2$ in matrix form ?

Here is a graph of the function and the supposed axes, that I obtained. [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8tucttwanq)

By principal axes, I'm refering to the axes about which the tensor of Inertia has only diagonal terms.

Comment: If we're not talking about a conic, what *are* principal axes of a curve? You haven't given a definition, and I certainly don't know one. You seem to be looking for points on the curve that are local extreme points for distance from "the origin." Is this your definition?

Comment: I've edited the question, please check. Also, I'm considering a closed curve here. Maybe a deformed circle or something like that.

Comment: You mean the inertia tensor of the *planar* region bounded by the curve? So this is going to reduce just to the $xy$ portion of the tensor, and a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix can always be orthogonally diagonalized, indeed. But for a general region I don't know a shortcut for finding the eigenvectors of that symmetric matrix.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is, how are we going to represent that planar region in the form of a symmetric matrix, if the curve is a polynomial of degree 4 for example.

Comment: You're not. The symmetric matrix to which I'm referring is the matrix of the inertia tensor.